# How Can I use a variable in a variable?

Tags: powershell, gui

The purpose of this form is to find the name of devices assigned to Exiting employees. Currently the only reference we have to a User/Device assignment is in the AD description field. I am having trouble getting the name entered into the `$Tbx_Leaver` field to pass to the variable $Leaver. if I enter a name in the leaver variable instead of the $Field name it works fine. What do I have wrong?

The extra text box in the form will be used to show the device name and I will add a button to disable the device in AD.

```
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);'

[void][Console.Window]::ShowWindow([Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow(), 0)
<# 
.NAME
    Template
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()



$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(400,400)
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$Lbl_Leaver                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Lbl_Leaver.Text                 = "Leaver Name"
$Lbl_Leaver.AutoSize             = $true
$Lbl_Leaver.width                = 25
$Lbl_Leaver.height               = 10
$Lbl_Leaver.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(11,8)
$Lbl_Leaver.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Tbx_Leaver                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Tbx_Leaver.Text                 = ""
$Tbx_Leaver.multiline            = $false
$Tbx_Leaver.width                = 200
$Tbx_Leaver.height               = 20
$Tbx_Leaver.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,43)
$Tbx_Leaver.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)

$Btn_Submit                      = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Btn_Submit.Text                 = "Submit"
$Btn_Submit.width                = 60
$Btn_Submit.height               = 30
$Btn_Submit.location             = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(28,88)
$Btn_Submit.Font                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$Btn_Submit.Add_Click({ Find_Leaver_Devices })

$Tbx_Device_Name                     = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Tbx_Device_Name.Text                = ""
$Tbx_Device_Name.multiline           = $false
$Tbx_Device_Name.width               = 100
$Tbx_Device_Name.height              = 20
$Tbx_Device_Name.location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13,192)
$Tbx_Device_Name.Font                = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Lbl_Leaver,$Tbx_Leaver,$Btn_Submit,$$Tbx_Device_Name))



Function Find_Leaver_Devices {
$Leaver = "*$Tbx_Leaver.Text*"
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=abc,OU=def,OU=ghi,DC=123,DC=456" -Filter {Description -Like $Leaver} -Properties *) | Select-Object Name, Description | Out-GridView -Passthru
}


[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just needed to remove the quotesaround the form field name in the $Leaver Variable.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `$$Tbx_Device_Name` needing to be `$Tbx_Device_Name`?